# Search multiple sheets for a word

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Hello Guys**
I have a sheet with multible sheets/pages where i would like to find a value that is stored in a cell. I trigger my script via a picture in a drawing.

In the example below i would like to search for the word Test. With my method i would need to but a picture on every site any search every site manually to find the word.

| Word | Number | Other |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Test | 2 | Hey |

I am alredy able to find a value one 1 page and "dispaly" it, but i would like to do it on all off the other sheets.
Here is the Code that I use to find something on the same Page.

```js
function searchString(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var search_string = sheet.getRange("J22:M23").getValue();
  var textFinder = sheet.createTextFinder(search_string);
  var search_row = textFinder.findNext().getRow();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert("search row: " + search_row);
}
```

I would like it diplay the page it was found in  and the row it is in, but i cant figure it out.

 **Thx for your help guys**

Comment: Do you want to search all the sheets in the spreadsheet or limit the search to the active Sheet? Do you want to search all the values in the range J22:M23. If so, you should use .getValues() and then loop throught the obtained array. If you want to search a single value, then your range should be a single cell... Please clarify.

Comment: OK sorry. I want to search all sheets in a spreadsheet. And J22:M23 is 1 connected cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to search a text from all sheets in a Google Spreadsheet.

  - From `var search_string = sheet.getRange("J22:M23").getValue()`, the value of `search_string` is one text.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `createTextFinder(findText)` of Class Sheet is used. In this case, `findText` is searched from a sheet. In order to search `findText` from all sheets in a Google Spreadsheet, you can use `createTextFinder(findText)` of Class Spreadsheet.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows.

```
function searchString(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var search_string = sheet.getRange("J22:M23").getValue();
  var textFinder = ss.createTextFinder(search_string);
  var search_rows = textFinder.findAll().map(r => ({sheetName: r.getSheet().getSheetName(), row: r.getRow()}));
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert("search row: " + JSON.stringify(search_rows));
}
```

- In this modified script, as a sample output value, the sheet name and row number are shown.

#### References:

- [createTextFinder(findText) of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#createtextfinderfindtext)
- [createTextFinder(findText) of Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#createTextFinder(String))

Comment: Is there a way to add a br after ever search result? i tried \r\n but it dosent seam to work

Comment: @Michael Krapf  Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about it, when you want to retrieve only the row numbers, how about `var search_rows = textFinder.findAll().map(r => r.getRow()).join("<br>");` or `var search_rows = textFinder.findAll().map(r => r.getRow()).join("\n");`? If I misunderstood your new question, I apologize.

Comment: No no really i think i worded my proplem poorly. So here it is again. The output of the code is `Search in: [{"sheetName":"Eingabe","row":22},{"sheetName":"Option1","row":8},{"sheetName":"Option1","row":14},{"sheetName":"Option5","row":3}]`but i would like it to be `Search in: [{"sheetName":"Eingabe","row":22},` a new line in the ui `{"sheetName":"Option1","row":8}]`

Comment: @Michael Krapf Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot understand your goal of new question. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal of new question? I would like to think of the solution of your new question by correctly understanding it. I apologize for this.

Comment: **thank you for your time.** `{"sheetName":"Eingabe","row":22}` Is the output of the code above. After every result i would like to get a new line in the ui window. The problem is there are multiple results in multiple sheets it gets hard to read. So it tould be nice if after every result it would start a new line.

Comment: @Michael Krapf Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your goal of new question, `ui.alert("search row:\n" + search_rows.map(e => JSON.stringify(e)).join("\n"))` instead of `ui.alert("search row: " + JSON.stringify(search_rows))` is what you want?

Comment: Yes it is. Thank you so much you are amazing.

Comment: @Michael Krapf Thank you for replying. I'm glad your new issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [code](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/14137):

```
function loopThroughSheets(cell) {
     //all sheets
     var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
     
     //loop
     for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length ; i++ ) {
          
          //current sheet and getting current value of cell
          var sheet = sheets[i];
          var val = sheet.getRange(cell).getValue();

          //do your job here     
     }
}
```