# I nead the value of a specific spreadsheet cell when I get the row number as a search answer

Tags: search, spreadsheet, multiple-results

I'm new in the forum and also not a programmer, so I apologize in advance for any mistakes.

I use a Google sheet as an order inventory. I use two sheets as datasheets with identical fields, one for current orders and one for old orders. I also have a third sheet which I use as user input form.

I'm trying to code a script for searching both datasheets for a string the users can put in a specific cell in the form, e.g. the name or the phonenumber of a customer. The results I need are all the orderIds which I store in column A in both datasheets.

With the following code that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67005296/search-multiple-sheets-for-a-word), I get as result the the name of the sheets and the row number. I need the name of the sheet so that the user knows if the customer has other orders, old or current and the value of A column for each result instead of the row number.

```
function searchString(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var search_string = sheet.getRange("C3").getValue();
  var textFinder = ss.createTextFinder(search_string);
  var search_rows = textFinder.findAll().map(r => ({sheetName: r.getSheet().getSheetName(), code: r.getRow()}));
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert(JSON.stringify(search_rows));
}
```

I also want to exclude the Form sheet from the search, but that's not so important.

Thanks in advance

Comment: First, I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. Also, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an working answer from a friend through email and I post the code here.

`

```
  function searchString(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var search_string = sheet.getRange("G12").getValue();
  var textFinder = ss.createTextFinder(search_string);
  var search_rows = textFinder.findAll().map(r => ({Sheet: r.getSheet().getSheetName(), Code: r.getSheet().getRange(r.getRow(), 1).getValue()}));
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert(JSON.stringify(search_rows));
}
```

`

Thanks for all the usefull code I find here.